# Certificate not recognized even after running sn -i

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

I have a certificate generated for code signing:

[image]

which I use in my VS solution to sign the assemblies.

After receiving this exception when building:

"Cannot import the following key file: xxx.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_xxx"

I had ran

```
sn -i xxx.pfx VS_KEY_xxx
```

and I can see the certificate is present at that key:

[image]

But VS continues to complain about not finding the certificate at that key.

Comparing this with the previous certificate used, i can see that the new one is registered as "Exchange" instead of "Signature", as the previous:

[image]

What drives that difference? Did I do something stupid when creating the certificate?

Any lead for this would be greatly appreciated.

If any additional info is needed, I remain at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have pinpointed the problem here: the new certificate is to broad purposed, and that's why it's not registered as "Signature", and hence VS cannot build the project. Will get back with more info once I am certain of the solution.

TBC